# Java CompletionHandler is thread safe

Tags: java

I Use `AsynchronousFileChannel` with `workerThreadPool`.

`CompletionHandler` in Global Area is Thread Safe?

I hope that workerThread each Readbyte and Make Each Object

This code safe? look At the completed method and private `MyObject`

I already finish test and Success 100 lines text

but, I steel worry mind. help me

```
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(260);
        AsynchronousFileChannel asyncFileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(
                Paths.get(sourceFilePath),
                StandardOpenOption.READ
        );

        asyncFileChannel.read(
                byteBuffer, 0, 0L, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Long>() {

                    List<String> jsonStrList = new ArrayList();

                    @Override
                    public void completed(Integer readSize, Long iterations) {   
                        try{
                            if (readSize == -1){
                                if(readSize == fileSize || readSize < byteBuffer.capacity()) {
                                    resultFlag.set(true);
                                }
                                return;
                            }

                            byteBuffer.flip();
                            byteBuffer.mark();

                            // check DATA AND LIST_ADD
                            String check = new String(byteBuffer.array());
                            if(check.startsWith("{")){
                                jsonStrList.add(check);
                            }
                            byteBuffer.reset();

                            if(readSize == fileSize || readSize < byteBuffer.capacity()) {
                                resultFlag.set(true);
                                return;
                            }

                            iterations++;
                            asyncFileChannel.read(byteBuffer, readSize * iterations, iterations, this);
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(Throwable exc, Long iterations) {  
                        throw new RuntimeException(exc.getMessage(), exc);
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: Your example code does not do anything, so obviously it is thread-safe!  If you want us to tell you whether your real code is thread-safe or not, show us an MVCE.

Comment: i'm sorry.. please  check my code please. 
CompletionHandler Interface in  look at the (List Variable Location - jsonStrList)

Comment: What does 'in global area' mean?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html) say, I think that thread-safety is not guaranteed for your code.

Firstly, the javadocs say that the completion handler code will (typically) be run on a different thread to the thread that called `read`.  See the paragraphs that talk about thread pools.  So thread-safety is a valid concern.

Secondly, while the javadocs say that an `AsyncFileChannel` instance is thread-safe, they also state this:

> The `ByteBuffers` used when reading or writing are not safe for use by multiple concurrent I/O operations.  Furthermore, after an I/O operation is initiated then care should be taken to ensure that the buffer is not accessed until after the operation has completed.

It is unclear whether that applies to what you are doing here.  It is debatable whether the read operation would be deemed to have "completed" if you are in the completion handler.

Anyhow:

- I wouldn't put that logic into an async handler.  It looks "too clever by half" to me.  IMO, you should be doing that with a dedicated thread and synchronous I/O.
- If I did persist with your approach, I would be inclined to use a primitive lock, volatile or atomic variable to *ensure* that there are no memory hazards related to the `ByteBuffer` being accessed by multiple threads.
- Also, the thread-safety of `resultFlag` needs to be considered.  (If it is an `AtomicBoolean`, it is OK.  Otherwise .... it depends.)
- Ditto for `jsonStrList.add(...)` and `iterations++`.